# Neuroscience- NIH-IRTA for a international student

Tags: research-undergraduate, internship, international

I've finished my bachelor in Cognitive science and mathematics and I'm looking for research opportunities in the US, starting in a half year. Are there any programs for people in my position? The NIH-IRTA only works for citizens and permanent residents. A year ago I've been on exchange to a top American college, but didn't make acquaintances with any of the PI, as the classes were lead by TA's; can I still use my exchange to find an internship somewhere in the US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the major US founders limited their funding of junior people to US citizens/permanent residents. these same funding bodies (e.g., NIH, NSF) will happily allow PIs to hire international people on grants. Your best bet is probably to find a PI who is willing to hire you directly off a grant.

Comment: I figured as much, but wanted to double check. I'm "new to the world of academia", so I don't know if there's a best way to approach PIs with these questions. Should I just send them a message about their research and asking about a job/internship?
PS I'm so surprised someone actually responded to this question, thank you!

Comment: @Peter that would make for a good new question (although you should search to make sure it hasn't been asked before).